# Can I pick items up without unequipping my tool?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

I often need to pick up items while I still have a tool out for some reason, particularly when chopping down trees or tending to crops. So far the only way I've found to pick up items is to press Y to put away my tool, then press A to pick items up.

Can I pick items up without unequipping my tools?

Answer (score 1):

After extensive pressing every button but Y, I'm pretty sure there's no way to do this without putting away your tools.